# Splitting datetime into various sections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord

I've got two fields `start_time` and `end_time` both of which are storing in the datetime format.

The problem I'd like some help with is, how do I use the date inputted from the start_time attribute to form the date for the end_time attribute (and just prompt for the time aspect) as the start+end time will have the same days, just the time will be different.

```
<div class="field">
       <%= f.label :start_time %>
       <%= f.datetime_select :start_time, :minute_step => 15, :default => Time.now+1.week, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :end_time  %>

        <%= f.time_select :end_time, :ignore_date => true, :minute_step => 15 %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this via javascript.

Use the on key up event.

```
$("#start").keyup(function(){
  ...
});
```

If you use jquery then use the .val() getter and setter on either input.

```
d = Date($("#start").val())

d2 = Date(d.getday(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());

$("#end").val(d2);
```

Something like that.

Format the date just using day month year, using the datetime object's  method for that purpose.

Comment: So by using hidden fields? Surely it would make more sense to construct the correct datetime in the model rather than on the front-end?

Comment: why do they have to be hidden?

Comment: how are you going to construct the date from the model if it is inputed? you're going to have to submit the form in order to fill out the second date. clearly you don't want that.

Comment: So the end_time would have the same date, as the date inputted for the start_time, they'd just have different times?

Comment: it would just have the date, or the inputed date plus the current hour. whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding a before_save method with the following code:

```
sale_times.each do |sale|
    sale.end_time = DateTime.parse("#{sale.start_time.strftime("%x")} #{sale.end_time}")
end
```

View code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %>
    <%= f.date_select :start_time, :minute_step => 15, :default => Time.now+1.week, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_time  %>      
    <%= f.time_select :end_time, :minute_step => 15 %>
</div>
```